# Generate List Based on Items in Other Lists

Tags: python, django, list

I was wondering if anyone could put me on the right path here.

I am working with Django and have querysets of items selected from the database. What i am trying to achieve is create a new list based off of the items in the querysets.

In each queryset the three fields are Lineclass, Diameter and Quantity.

Each item in 'Fieldwelds' would have a lineclass, diameter, and quantity. Each item in 'Demolengths' would have a lineclass, diameter and quantity.

I am trying to create a list, where each item in the list, is a list of all lineclass items from each queryset.

E.g If Fieldwelds and Demolengths both have a lineclass of 11011, and both have a diameter of 20, i need a list in the main list to be something like `Line11011['Diameter', Fieldwelds, Demolengths], Line11071['Diameter', Fieldwelds, Demolengths], Masterlist = [Line11011, Line11071]`.

I honestly can't see how i can do something like this. Could anyone offer some advice?

EDIT:

```
class FieldWeldsBase(models.Model):
    lineclass = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    diameter = models.FloatField()
    quantity = models.SmallIntegerField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    workpack = models.ForeignKey(Workpack, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.lineclass + ' ' + self.workpack.workpacknumber

class DemoLengthBase(models.Model):
    lineclass = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    diameter = models.FloatField()
    quantity = models.SmallIntegerField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    workpack = models.ForeignKey(Workpack, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.lineclass + ' ' + self.workpack.workpacknumber
```

I hope this is what you are looking for. The only information i need from the models to create the list are the lineclass, diameter and quantity.

Comment: Please can you show your models? There's probably a way of getting what you want directly from the database.

Comment: Can you explain why you have two identical models? Why not one model with a "type" attribute of 'demolength'/'fieldwelds'?

Comment: Have you considered making a LineClass model and combining FieldWelds and DemoLength into a single model? I can't quite understand what you are trying to achieve here, but it looks like something that could be achieved with regular django queries if you model your data differently.

Comment: Thanks guys for trying to help. As far as i can tell, even if the items were all stored under one table, i would be faced with the same problem. If i have a fieldweld with a lineclass of 11011, and diameter of 20, and a demolength with lineclass 11011 and a diameter of 20. I need them stored in a single list. The only way i can see to create this is to create many lists. E.g Line_11011_20 (11011 being the lineclass, and 20 being the diameter). Then Line_11011_25, with 11011 being the lineclass and 25 being the diameter.  I have over 50 diameters and 10 lineclass, so would end up with 500 lists